# I am not able to preview the icons on vscode while browsing?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[image]

As seen in the picture I'm browsing the icons but none of them are shown.
Is there a change in a new update or am I missing something here> it used to show the icons while I browsed.

Comment: VS code is working completely fine. If it doesn't show up directly while selecting just press ctrl + spacebar, that should bring up the icon preview.

Comment: yeah as you can see in the picture, it doesn't show anytthing

Comment: You'll have to press ctrl+space again, after the auto-complete dropdown is already showing

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There should be an arrow appearing when you hover on the right side of the tooltip stating "read more". Simply click once and therefore the icons preview should always appear.

[image]

Comment: yeap that was it. realized it a few days ago lol

Comment: Doesn't work for me https://i.postimg.cc/FzQCkg0f/Untitled.png

Answer (score 15):

Pressing the `Ctrl + space` in windows can show and hide the icon

Comment: works for Linus:Ubuntu too

Answer (score 5):

press ctrl+space two times,
1)to open icon menu
2)to preview the icon

Answer (score 3):

go to preferences settings and search for "previewlsp" its a dart setting change it to true and restart VsCode then you will be able to preview icons.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I maximized the VSCode editor, closed the navigation pane on left, and aligned the line most left then icon preview comes into the screen as you can see in the picture.

I don't know the root cause of the problem but the above scenario fixed my issue and it works now. It might be a Flutter/Dart extension-related topic.

If I would find the real root cause and proper solution, I will update my answer. I hope this workaround works for you too.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX5M9.png)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with setting Dart Preview Flutter Ui Guides setting

1. Go to Setting and search "preview"
2. Go to Dart part(see the left part)
3. check Dart:Preview Flutter Ui Guides
   [Setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHJ4j.png)