# Flutter IconData preview doesn't show in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

As shown in the picture above, I cannot see any IconData preview. It only prints a message like shown. In [similar question I've read earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853635/i-am-not-able-to-preview-the-icons-on-vscode-while-browsing), I still can't manage to figure out how to show the IconData preview, like in [this Flutter tutorial video](https://youtu.be/jNDsTI-poYo?t=316)

How do I enable this feature? Is it because of recent update or something?

Comment: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1181

Comment: It's enabled by default. If you think this is a bug notify VS Code development team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue - there's an open GitHub issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2896.

The way these icons are embedded doesn't allow them to easily be rendered, and the original extension code would use a regex to find/replace them. This has become slightly more complicated in the move to [LSP](https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol), though I have some ideas to try to fix it soon.

Answer (score 4):

Pressing **ctrl + space** in windows can show and hide the icon

Comment: Wow this is what it was! I don't recall having to do this in Mac